# Set ICollection<int> property as Foreign Keys to ICollection<User> in EntityTypeConfiguration class

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I'm developing and Entity Framework Code First 6.1.0 library with .NET Framework 4.5.1 and C#.

I have this class:

```
public class Message
{
    public int MessageId { get; set; }
    public string Body { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateSent { get; set; }

    public Nullable<int> GroupId { get; set; }
    public Group FromGroup { get; set; }

    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public User Sender { get; set; }

    public ICollection<User> Recipients { get; set; }
}
```

With this configuration class:

```
public class MessageConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Message>
{
    public MessageConfiguration()
    {
        ToTable("Message");

        Property(m => m.Body).IsRequired();
        Property(m => m.Body).IsMaxLength();

        Property(m => m.DateSent).IsRequired();

        HasOptional(m => m.FromGroup).
            WithMany(g => g.Messages).
            HasForeignKey(m => m.GroupId);

        HasRequired(m => m.Sender).
            WithMany(u => u.MessagesSent).
            HasForeignKey(m => m.UserId).
            WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

        HasMany(r => r.Recipients).
            WithMany(m => m.MessagesReceived).
            Map(mr =>
            {
                mr.ToTable("MessageRecipient");
                mr.MapLeftKey("MessageId");
                mr.MapRightKey("UserId");
            });
    }
}
```

As you can see, if **I create a new `Message` class instance**, I can use `UserId` or `Sender` property to set the message's sender. I can also do the same with `GroupId` and `FromGroup`.

But, if I want to set user's recipients I have to set `Users' class` instances but I can't use Users' ids.

How can I do that?

My problem is that I don't know how to tell E.F. that those Ids are `Recipients`' foreign keys like I did with `Sender` and `UserId`:

```
HasRequired(m => m.Sender).
WithMany(u => u.MessagesSent).
HasForeignKey(m => m.UserId).
WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

I want to create a new property on `Message` class:

```
public ICollection<int> RecipientsId;
```

because I want to create a new message class instance, and set their recipients using user's ID.

I don't know how to modify EntityTypeConfiguration to tell E.F. that that new `ICollection<int> RecipientsId` property has `ICollection<User> Recipients`'s Foreign Keys.

**NOTE**: I'm going to use this library on an ASP.NET Web API 2 service and I want to send `int` values as Recipients, instead of sending `User` instances.

Comment: Why would you need, `public ICollection<int> RecipientIds`, you have `ICollection<User> Recipients`, so if you want there id's you can just use linq `Recipients.Select(x => x.UserId)`

Comment: Please, read the note at the end of my question. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`Recipients.Select(x => x.UserId)` will return a list of int values.  If you want this on your model then simply create a property as below.

```
IEnumerable<int> RecipientIds
{
    get
    {
        return Recipients.Select(x => x.UserId);
    }
}
```

As this property only has a getter EF should not try to map it to a DB field.

Comment: No, I'm not asking that. I want to create a new Message class instance, and set their recipients using User's Id.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand what you are asking then. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: If I create a new Message, I can set `message.UserId = 1` instead of set `message.Sender = user1`. I can do that because I set on `MessageConfiguration` that `Sender` property has `UserId` property as Foreign Key. I want to do the same with `RecipientIds`: set recpients' Ids as `int` values instead of create `User` instance to do the same (indicate that they are the recipients).

Comment: I don't think you can do that with a many to many relationship becuase in the underlying DB you will have a `MessageRecipient` table that maps between you Message  and User table.  You could i think create a MessageRecipient entity for this table and insert a MessageRecipient entity with a UserId and a MessageId property. I haven't tried exactly that so you will have to give it a go.

Comment: However you don't have to do this, if you have a list of UserIds, just fetch the Users from the database and add them to your existing Recipients collection.

Comment: Yes, but I will do this throw an ASP.NET Web Api service, and it could consume a lot of bandwidth.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand how it being a Web API service is relevent to the question.

Comment: Ah, ok. I have understand it. You are right, it is not relevant.

Answer (score 0):

after i trying for hours, pass `int` can not be done, alternatively you can add user by FindBy UserId

```
var user = context.Users.Find(UserId);
msg.UserReceipts.Add(User);
```

ps: sorry for my mistake in prev post.